# Select only one cell in datagridview when rightclick

Tags: c#, datagridview, mouseevent

in my application i have a datagridview with many rows. i want to add a feature to pop up context menu when user right click in certain cell. but only way to select a cell is left click in default. so i searched little bit and i found this code

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                var hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                dataGridView1.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;
            }
        }
```

but the problem of this code is after i put this code to mousedown when i right click wholw row is selected.but i only want to select one cell

how can i fix this

Comment: As @Tea With Cookies noted, if you have an additional question outside the scope of your original question, please ask a new question. This will help you and others with similar questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the advice sir. i marked it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the behaviour you want you have to:

-Make sure you have in your `dataGridView1` properties `SelectionMode = CellSelect` or `SelectionMode = RowHeaderSelect` (depending if you want the user to be able to select the whole row)

-Make these changes on your code:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                var hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
                if (hti.RowIndex >= 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[hti.ColumnIndex, hti.RowIndex];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks sir your solution is working perfectly. but i want change my edit feature to select full row and then edit or delete. i updated my question, can you please look in to it

Comment: @charith If you have another question, please open another topic and mark this one as answered :)

Comment: Im sorry sir i'm new to this site :( i really don't know how things going here  i'll mark this as an answer. anyway thanks for the answer again. your answer is extremely helpful for me